# Registration and Login with multiple platforms

Tags: authentication, cross-platform, oauth-2.0, facebook-login

I am eager to see some suggestions on login system. Say the corporate company has few (10) sites with same login credentials. Already single sign on is implemented based on WIF. Lets ignore WIF for now. I would like to bring some login and registration system.

The registration and login could be done through any one of the list(facebook, twitter,linkedin,google etc). Off course right now I have done this with ASP.net 4.0 framework and supports only asp.net applications.

I am looking for some explanations to bring "Common Registration and Login system" for all the  10 sites and with any platform, say .Net, Classic ASP, PHP.

Can some one say some overall idea about above mentioning.

Finally I am expecting to do a single login system, which could be easily integrated with any new site with any platform.

Any suggestions and idea would be more appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think facebook it's a good choice, they have the sdk for working with facebook and handles most of what you need, This is the advantage.

But in your 10 sites and in futures ones, you problably have roles and permission to users. you will have to implement the membership and then when a user login with facebook create the user in your system.

But the login with facebook brings new username and possible new email that may not be associated with the users that you have in the current application.

FAcebook, oauth-2.0 if you have to do roles this is maneged by you application.